# MFC dialog frozen

Tags: multithreading, mfc, dialog, serial-port, modem

I need help how to unfreeze my dialog box. I'm using MFC and I have an infinite loop I want to execute when a button is pressed. However, the dialog box freezes when the infinite loop starts. Now I looked at [this thread](http://forums.codeguru.com/archive/index.php/t-498486.html)  where someone was having a similar problem.

Unfortunately I tried multithreading but I found out that It can't work for me because I'm using an api that uses OLE automation and I'm getting an unhandled memory exception. I think this is because program uses the serial port and i read somewhere you can only use the handle to the serial port in one thread.

My program is simply to see if someone has dialed in to my modem and wait for them to send me a file, then hangup. Here is my loop.

```
while(1)
    {
        //get rid of input buffer
        ts->_this->m_pHAScript->haReleaseRemoteInput();
        ts-> _this->textBox->SetWindowTextA("thread Commence");
        //wait for connected
        if(success = ts->_this->m_pHAScript->haWaitForString("CONNECT",timeout))
        {
            //getFile
            if(success = ts->_this->m_pHAScript->haWaitForXfer(5000))
            {
                //hangup
                ts->_this->haTypeText("+++ath\r");
            }
        }

    }
```

Is there a way to unfreeze the dialog box?

Comment: You can still use multithreading with OLE automation. But you have to call OleInitialize() at the start of every thread!

Answer (score 1):

Add this code inside while loop:

```
MSG msg;
while(PeekMessage(&msg, GetSafeHwnd(), 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
{
  DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Comment: And hope you don't run into any nasty reentrance bugs.

Comment: I'm sorry to say but your solution does not work. That loop causes my loop to break and also, my program doesen't close. My debug stays open and some of the processes that the program starts also stay open

Answer (score 1):

The GUI in Windows relies on a message loop - somewhere in your code, either explicitly or hidden in a framework, there's a loop that checks for a message in a queue and processes it. If anything blocks the code from returning to that loop, the GUI gets frozen.

There are a few ways around this. One was given by [David Brabant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10624210/5987), essentially duplicating the loop. Another is to start a new "worker" thread that runs the blocking operation independently. If your message loop has a function that it calls when it is idle, i.e. no more messages are in the queue, you can do some processing there; that's not possible in your example however.

Comment: The problem with David's solution is that although the window closes when i press the close button, the loop does not break. How can I check the messages to see if the close button was press

Comment: @Mozly, in the PeekMessage loop you can check to see if the message is `WM_QUIT` - if so you should exit your outer loop. Because you're calling blocking functions `haWaitForString` and `haWaitForXfer` I doubt that his solution will work for you because you won't execute the `PeekMessage` loop often enough.